# How these are valid if the coordinate is a right-handed coordinate system?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, vectors, vector-fields

I am trying to understand how $(1),(2) \text{ and } (3)$  are valid if the coordinate is a right-handed coordinate system. The definition of a right-handed coordinate system is a one such that $\overrightarrow{i} \times \overrightarrow{j} =  \overrightarrow{k}$ is valid. To me, to prove that I must compute all possibilities to verify that result. Is there any other method?

$$\overrightarrow{i} \times \overrightarrow{j} =  \overrightarrow{k} \qquad(1)\\ 
  \overrightarrow{j} \times \overrightarrow{k} =  \overrightarrow{i} \qquad(2)\\
  \overrightarrow{k} \times \overrightarrow{i} =  \overrightarrow{j} \qquad(3)$$

I want to very that $(1),(2) \text{ and } (3)$ is valid as long as it is a right-handed coordinate system. what I mean by possibilities is to try all the different ways that $x,y$ and $z$ can be. For example:

[image]   [image]

[image]

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Computing_the_cross_product]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're looking for here?  What are you trying to prove?  What possibilities are you referring to?

Comment: @J. Murray I have adjusted it. Please, tell me if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

(1) holds in a right-handed coordinate system by definition. To show that (2) and (3) also hold, replace $\vec k$ by $\vec{i}\times\vec{j}$ in them and then expand the [double cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product).

Comment: Can you please explain what the double cross product is? And how it can be applied (some derivation)?

Comment: I’ve added a link with the relevant identities. They are a standard part of vector algebra.

Comment: In the proof they assume that  $\overrightarrow{j} \times \overrightarrow{k} =  \overrightarrow{i} \qquad(2) \\ \overrightarrow{k} \times \overrightarrow{i} =  \overrightarrow{j} \qquad(3)$     are correct, and this is what I want to prove.

Comment: You can assume any of the three and then prove the other two. You said that (1) was the definition of a right-handed system, but if you want to assume (2) instead of (1) it works similarly.

Comment: [chat] https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106530/cross-product

Comment: Hold the thumb, index finger, and middle finger of your **left** hand in orthogonal positions. Now denote your left thumb as pointing in the $\hat i$ direction, left index finger as pointing in the $\hat j$ direction, and left middle finger as pointing in the $\hat k$ direction. Next define the cross products $\hat i \times \hat j = \hat k$, $\hat j \times\hat k = \hat i$, and $\hat k \times \hat i = \hat j$. **It all works.** There is nothing special about a right handed coordinate system.